# HTT, 4.3.1.5, Lurie, Functoriality of Slice Categories

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

> I am looking at the statment which says that replacing equivalent diagrams preserves colimits. This is [4.3.1.5(3), p262](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HTT.pdf).

[image]

> This  seems intuitively true but I am unable to write it out rigorously. It would be nice if someone explains some details.

An equivalent question would be

> Let $p,q:K \rightarrow C$ be two simplicial maps between simplicial sets. Suppose we have a natural transformation $\alpha:p \rightarrow q$. How doesd one naturally construct map 
>   $C_{p/} \rightarrow C_{q/}$?