# How does one define constant functor of simplicial sets?

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, functors, higher-category-theory

In [HA, p142, Lem 1.4.2.10](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HA.pdf) Lurie makes the following construction,

> Let $C. D$ be $\infty$-categories which admits final objects. Let $D$ have final object $*'$.  Let $X:C \rightarrow D$ be *the constant functor* taking value $*'$.

How is *the constant functor* constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the composite of the unique simplicial map $C\to \Delta^0$ with the map $\Delta^0\to D$ representing $*'$. Note that maps $\Delta^0\to D$ are naturally bijective with elements of $D(0)$ by Yoneda.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Do you mind also commenting on this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3440094/htt-4-3-1-5-lurie-functoriality-of-slice-categories